# Diferencia entre formulario HTML y Formulario ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Me pueden ayudar diciéndome cuál es la diferencia entre un formulario HTML y un formulario ASP.NET. No son lo mismo, ¿por qué?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cabe resaltar que el resultado final usando uno u otro va a ser código HTML por lo que ambos son lo mismo hasta cierto punto. La diferencia que existe en los formularios ASP.Net y la ventaja que trae consigo su uso son los llamados "Helpers HTML", así como la facilidad de crear formularios basados en clases de modelo ahorrándote tiempo a la hora de escribir código en tus formularios. También permite explotar al máximo las cualidades de ASP.Net, ejemplo de ello son las validaciones, tanto del lado del cliente como en tu modelo mediante anotaciones. Pero como te decía al principio, al final todo será reducido a HTML, por lo que un formulario html también puede ser usado, solo que tendrías que gastar parte de tu tiempo en escribir algo de código siempre con la posibilidad de que tengas algún error, cosa que los Formularios de ASP hacen por ti.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado te comento un poco.
HTML es un lenguaje del lado del cliente, mientras que ASP es un lenguaje de servidor.

ASP.Net se utiliza para diseñar páginas dinamica, mientras que HTML se utiliza para diseñar páginas estáticas.

ASP.NET permite usar y crear controles html complejos reutilizables, usando un lenguaje de programación.

Las páginas HTML no pueden conectarse a una base de datos directamente pero con las páginas ASP.NET si se podría.

En cuanto a los controles de asp.net y los controles html

Las etiquetas HTML son conocidas son standares y faciles de usar por diseñadores web pero las etiquetas asp.net tienen etiquetas como  estos son controles de servidor y si un diseñador web no conoce de asp.net dificilmente lo podra manejar.

Controles de servidor HTML: son etiquetas HTML comprendidas por el servidor.
Para que estos elementos HTML se puedan programar deberás agregar un atributo runat="server" al elemento HTML. 
Este attributo indica que el elemento debe tratarse como un control de servidor.

Todos los controles de servidor HTML deben estar dentro de una etiqueta  con el atributo runat="server". 
El atributo runat="server" indica que el formulario debe procesarse en el servidor. 
También indica que los controles adjuntos pueden ser accedidos por scripts de servidor.

Si deseas saber un poco mas sobre las ventajas y desventajas de ambos puedes acudir a la pagina [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67276kc5.aspx.](http://Descripci%C3%B3n%20general%20de%20la%20arquitectura%20del%20comportamiento%20de%20control%20adaptativo)

Answer (score 0):

Un formulario HTML es aquel que la página tiene formato .html. Emplea un lenguaje de marcas HTML para crear el esqueleto, CSS para indicar los estilos... pero no contiene código de programación en el servidor de la web.

Un formulario ASP.NET es aquel que la página tiene formato .asp tiene además de todo lo mencionado en el formulario HTML, código que se interpretará en el servidor y será ejecutado en el servidor y enviado al navegador sin el código de programación en cuestión.

Para poder hacer páginas dinámicas que vayan cambiando con el comportamiento o uso, es necesario uso de lenguajes de programación (llamados del lado del cliente) como JavaScript para que desde el cliente se puedan definir ciertos comportamientos. Pero, muchas veces, necesitarás que sea “la página” la que compruebe un dato, o lea de una base de datos, etc y aquí es donde entran en juego los lenguajes de programación “llamados del lado del servidor) ASP.NET en este caso.

Para reconocer si necesitas un tipo de formulario u otro, debes hacerte esta pregunta. ¿Necesitas que tu página se comunique con el dispositivo que la llamó y reaccione ante estas comunicaciones?

En caso afirmativo no lo dudes, necesitas un formulario ASP.NET

Comment: en conclusion, un formulario asp es el que en el form tiene codigo inyectado ASP.NET?

Comment: Exacto y ampliando lo dicho... el hecho de agregar un formulario ASP a tu web lo convierte en una página con extensión ASP. Es decir, no puedes meter código ASP a una web con extensión HTML.